# Changing specific array value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I currently have the following array in javascript

```
var chart1data = [
{ "Time": "1", "Temperature": 60, },
{ "Time": "2", "Temperature": 50, },
{ "Time": "3", "Temperature": 42, },
{ "Time": "4", "Temperature": 35, },
{ "Time": "5", "Temperature": 28, },
{ "Time": "6", "Temperature": 24, },
{ "Time": "7", "Temperature": 21, },
{ "Time": "8", "Temperature": 19, },
{ "Time": "9", "Temperature": 18, },
{ "Time": "10", "Temperature": 18, },
];
```

I have a button, in my HTML which when pressed, should change the value "60" in the above array to another number (for example - 80)

The button links to this function. How can I make it so this  works?

```
 function updatechart (){

//This gets the number from a text box 
 var inputdata1 = document.getElementById("textbox1").innerHTML

//Now I need the code to put this number in replace of the value "60" 
 }
```

Comment: Are you using `innerHTML` to get the value of a text input...?

Comment: why in place of 60 and not any other?

Comment: `chart1data[index].Temperature = inputdata1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your array as follows:

```
chart1data[index].Temperature = inputdata1;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/sPTG8/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: This works fine. However because the innerHTML is  a string and not a value the action I need it for is not work. How do I convert the innerHTML (for exaaple 80 or whatever) to 80 as a value

Comment: Try changing innerHTML to value like this: `var inputdata1 = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change 60 then:

```
chart1data[0].Temperature = inputdata1;
```

else

```
chart1data[index].Temperature = inputdata1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you have an `array` of `object`. Said objects contain 2 properties, `Time` and `Temperature`. To access an object within the array, assuming you know the index, you can do:

```
alert(chart1data[index].Time) // alerts the time of the first item
chart1data[index].Temperature = 60; // sets the temperature of the first item
```

Alternatively, if you want to replace **all** temperature values that are 60, you can loop through your items and simply update them, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart1data.length; i++) {
    if (chart1data[i].Temperature == '60') {
        chart1data[i].Temperature = '80'
    }
}
```